Using separable differential equation solve $\left(xy^2 + y + x + 1\right)dx + \left(y - 1\right)dy = 0$ , $y(2) = 0$
Solve the initial value problem using separable differential equations.
$\left(xy^2 + y + x + 1\right)dx + \left(y - 1\right)dy = 0$ , $y(2) = 0$
Here's my solution. I must have made a mistake in my solution as it leads to an undefined value.

My attempt to separate the $x$ and $y$ variables

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-(xy^2+y^2+x+1)}{y-1}$
$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-[y^2(x+1)+(x+1)]}{y-1}$
$\frac{(y-1)dy}{y^2} = (x+1)+(x+1) dx$

Integrating both sides

$\int \frac{(y-1)}{y^2}\, dy = \int(x+1)+(x+1)\, dx $
$\int \frac{1}{y}\, dy - \int \frac{1}{y^2}\, dy = \int x\, dx + \int 1\, dx + \int x\, dx + \int 1\, dx $
$\ln \left| y \right| + \frac{1}{y}\ = x^2+2x+C$

Solve for $C$

$y(2) = 0$,
$\ln \left| 0 \right| + \frac{1}{0}\ = 2^2+2(2)+C$
The C leads to an undefined value.

Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Thank you for your comment. I hope my revision helps.

Yes. It is better now.

The second equation in your post is not consistent with the first one.

Hints: After $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-[y^2(x+1)+(x+1)]}{y-1}$ your next step is wrong. Write $\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-[y^{2}+1]}{y-1} (x+1)$ which gives $\frac {y-1}{y^{2}+1}dy=-(x+1)dx$. I will let you carry out the integration from here.
